# I need to get rid of the error "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" in my simple selenium code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng

> 1. Below is a very simple code for understanding Testng,but I am getting an issue as ->[TestNG] Reporter org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@82d64 failed
>      java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
> 2. How can I avoid/handle this error in the below code.

```
package demotestng2;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod; 
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod; 
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass; 
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest; 
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite; 
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;


 public class simpletestngtrycheckannotopttry1 {        
    /*  
       @Test(dataProvider = "dp")   public void f(Integer n, String s) {   }
    */

     @Test
     public void testCase1() {
        System.out.println("This is my First Test Case 1");
     }

     @BeforeMethod
     public void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println(" Before Method will execute before every test method");
     }


     @AfterMethod
     public void afterMethod() {
         System.out.println("After Method will execute after every test method");
     }


    /*
     @DataProvider
     public Object[][] dp() {
           return new Object[][] {
                new Object[] { 1, "a" },
                new Object[] { 2, "b" },
           };
     }

    */

     @BeforeClass
     public void beforeClass() {
           System.out.println("Before Class will always execute prior to Before Method and Test Method ");
     }

     @AfterClass
     public void afterClass() {
         System.out.println("After Class will always execute later to After Method and Test method");

     }

     @BeforeTest
     public void beforeTest() {
          System.out.println("Before Test will always execute prior to Before Class, ,Before Method and Test Method ");
     }


     @AfterTest
     public void afterTest() {
         System.out.println("After Test will always execute later to After Method, After Class ");
     }

     @BeforeSuite
     public void beforeSuite() {
          System.out.println("Before Suite will always execute prior to all annotations or tests in the suite.");
     }

     @AfterSuite
     public void afterSuite() {
         System.out.println("After suite will always execute at last when all the annotations or test in the suite have run.");
     }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason a ConcurrentModificationException would be thrown from the code you've posted. These tend to be related to trying to modify a collection while you are looping through it, and all the code above is doing is sysouts. Can you please attach the entire stack trace.

Comment: I would suggest that you make use of the latest released version of TestNG viz., `6.14.3` and try again. This error seems to be triggering from one of the default TestNG reporters which is not in your control and so you cannot do anything to prevent it, except for unhooking it.

Comment: I didn't find any issue in your code. It is running fine. You may change the testng version. I used testNG version 6.8.5. You may try with this version.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known [issue](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1168)

Please update your TestNG version, [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng) you can find all versions.